# Example of a sequence of Borel measures that converges weakly, but does not converge in Lévy–Prokhorov metric

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence, borel-measures

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal P(X)$ the space of all Borel probability measures on $X$. We endow $\mathcal P(X)$ with the [Lévy–Prokhorov metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric#Definition) $d_P$. Let $\mathcal C_b(X)$ be the space of all continuous bounded real-valued functions on $X$.

Then I have a theorem.

> Let $\mu, \mu_1, \mu_2,\ldots \in \mathcal P(X)$ such that $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $d_P$. Then $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly, i.e.,
> $$
> \int_X f \mathrm d\mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d\mu \quad \forall f \in\mathcal C_b(X).
> $$

1. 

This suggests that there exist an example of $\mu, \mu_1, \mu_2,\ldots \in \mathcal P(X)$ such that $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly but $\mu_n \not\to \mu$ in $d_P$.

> Could you give me such an example?

2. 

Assume that $\mu, \mu_1, \mu_2,\ldots \in \mathcal P(X)$ such that $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly. We only have that $\mu_n(A) \to \mu (A)$ for all Borel sets $A$ such that $\mu(\partial A)=0$.

It seems quite "unsatisfactory" to me that the limit $\mu$ is unique, but we can only recover information of $\mu$ for such Borel sets $A$ whose boundary has $0$ probability.

> Can we recover $\mu(A)$ from a sequence $(\mu_n)$ for every Borel set $A$?

3. In the same spirit as 2., now we assume $\mu, \mu_1, \mu_2,\ldots \in \mathcal P(X)$ such that $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $d_P$.

> Can we recover $\mu(A)$ from a sequence $(\mu_n)$ for every Borel set $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) If the space is separable, Levy Prokhorov convergence is equivalent to weak convergence. In the no separable case (which is not very interesting for probability applications), I'm not even sure the direct implication is true either.

2,3)Let $\mu_n = 1/n(\delta_{1/n} +...+\delta_{n/n})$. Then $\mu_n\to \mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ but $\mu_n(\mathbb Q)\not\to \mu(\mathbb Q)$

Comment: In "...not even sure the direct implication is true either", Could you elaborate which "direct implication" you meant?

Comment: What I mean is that the non separable case, I think you could even cook up an example where $\mu_n$ goes to $\mu$ in LP but not weakly. Weak convergence in non separable spaces is weird hence probabilistic avoid working in such spaces.