# Does $\mu_n (B) \to \mu(B)$ for all Borel set $B$ implies $\mu_n \to \mu$ in Lévy–Prokhorov metric?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{P} :=\mathcal{P}(X)$ the set of all Borel probability measures on $X$. Let $d_P$ be the [Prokhorov metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric) on $\mathcal{M}$. Let $\mu,\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots \in \mathcal P$.

(a) $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly.

(b) $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $d_P$.

(c) $\mu_n(B) \to \mu(B)$ for all $B \in \mathcal B(X)$.

We have (b) implies (a). Also, (c) implies (a). On the other hand, (b) does not imply (c). An [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4438708/368425) is as follows. Let $X := \mathbb R$ and $\mu_n := \delta_{1/n}$. Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$. Then $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly. Because $\mathbb R$ is separable, we also have $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $d_P$. However, $1=\mu_n(\mathbb Q) \not\to \mu(\mathbb Q)=0$.

Can we prove that (c) implies (b), or at least for a subsequence in (b)?

Comment: Yes, because then $\mu_n(B)\to\mu(B)$ for all $B\in{\cal B}(X)$ continuity set of $\mu$ (i.e., such that $\mu(\partial B)=0$). This is equivalent to (a) (and (b)).

Comment: @nejimban May I miss something? "$\mu_{n}(B) \to \mu(B)$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ continuity set of $\mu$ (i.e., such that $\mu(\partial B)=0$)" is equivalent to weak convergence but may be strictly weaker than (b) in case $X$ is not separable.

Comment: Indeed; bad habit to assume the space is Polish…